# using a third-party library's output directly in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa-touch

a friend of mine has developed a library, and I want to use it. I don't know how. His library is obfuscated as much as I know, his library is not in cocoa pod, and all I have is the build output of his library project. How can I use this library?

Comment: What is the extension of the library? .a or .framework ?